# Cohomology of projective space with coefficient $MU^q$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $MU$ be the complex cobordism. I want to compute the groups $H^p(\mathbb{R}P^n;MU^q)$. If $p > n$, then the group is $0$. It is $MU^* = \mathbb{Z}[t_1, \ldots,]$ with $\mathrm{deg}(t_i) = 2^i$ (the so called Lazard ring). The paper I am reading states that $H^p(\mathbb{R}P^n, MU^q) = 0$ unless $ 0 \leq p \leq n$ and $q \leq 0$. That $0 \leq p \leq n$ is necessary is clear, but why is $q \leq 0$ necessary, and isn't $MU^q = 0$ for $q < 0$ and therefore $H^p(\mathbb{R}P^n, MU^q) = 0$ in this case, since $MU^* = \mathbb{Z}[t_1, \ldots,]$ has only elements in positive degrees?

Comment: Why is this tagged algebraic-geometry and ring-theory? This seems to be purely an algebraic-topology question.

Comment: Given a spectrum $E$, the typical convention is $E^q = \pi_{-q} E$, with a sign flip between homological vs. cohomological grading.

Comment: But why isn't $MU^q = 0$?